# Execute multiple sentences at a time in iSQL*PLUS

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Sorry about this newbie question.

Is there a way to execute multiple sentences at a time in **iSQL*PLUS**

When I execute a single `insert` all runs ok, but is I write two inserts an error appear:

```
Falta una palabra clave ora-00905
```

Translation: "missing word key"

**Edited**

I have test with and without ";"

Notice that is iSQL*PLUS and not SQL*PLUS.

Just two inserts:

```
insert into myTable( f1, f2 ) values (1,2)
insert into myTable( f1, f2 ) values (1,2)
```

Error: ORA-00905

test 2:

```
insert into myTable( f1, f2 ) values (1,2);
insert into myTable( f1, f2 ) values (1,2);
```

Error: ORA-00911

test 3:

```
insert into myTable( f1, f2 ) values (1,2)  
/
insert into myTable( f1, f2 ) values (1,2)
/
```

Error: ORA-00933

test 4:

```
insert into myTable( f1, f2 ) values (1,2)  
\
insert into myTable( f1, f2 ) values (1,2)
\
```

Error: ORA-00911

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to try would be to wrap your inserts in an Anonymous Block. Might be a bit kludgey but if it gets the job done:

```
BEGIN
   insert into myTable( f1, f2 ) values (1,2);
   insert into myTable( f1, f2 ) values (1,2);
END;
```

You might need to put a "/" after it.